# django: getting error in django registration, in _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

I want to use django's registration form, for that i installed django-registration-redux.i have changed my settings.py accordingly. im new to django so by reading this error message i can not resolved this. plz help

```
settings.py

"""
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))




DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'registration',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myregi.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myregi.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

```
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('accounts', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
]
```

```py
blog.urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import index
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns= [

    url(r'', index, name="index"),

]
```

```py
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Detail
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.

@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
def index (request):
    n = Detail.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'data': n})
```

```py
models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Detail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```html
index.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>my blogs</h1>
{{data}}
{% endblock %}
```

now I'm getting error: TypeError at _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

but i'm couldn't resolve my error by reading this message

Comment: You shouldn't be using method_decorator there. Just do `@login_required`.

Comment: @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/') this line i added , now getting another error like infinite loop of address   ````[17/Nov/2019 20:04:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Nov/2019 ] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Nov/2019 ] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/login/%3Fnext%3D/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Nov/2019 ] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/login/%3Fnext%3D/accounts/login/%253Fnext%253D/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Nov/2019 ] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/login/%3Fnext%3D/accounts/login/%253Fnext%253D/accounts/login/%25253Fnext%25253D/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
...